# Cloning content from 1 div to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 90+ divs with an image/icon in each div. I want it so that when I click one of them, that image appears in another div. What would be a decent way to do this? I don't know much about JS yet, so a little example of this with HTML would be appreciated, also limited to html5, Ajax and js.

EDIT: I should clarify that the div I want the content to go into is already made, it doesn't have to be created as well.

```
<link href="CSS/mainSource.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body onLoad="display()">

<div id="testBox">
<div id="contentScroller">

<!-- I want to click one of these... -->

<div id="ahri"><img src="images/LoLchamps/Ahri.png" width="64" height="64"></div>
<div id="akali"><img src="images/LoLchamps/Akali.png" width="64" height="64"></div>
<div id="alistar"><img src="images/LoLchamps/Alistar.png" width="64" height="64"></div>
<div id="amumu"><img src="images/LoLchamps/Amumu.png" width="64" height="64"></div>

<!-- ...and clone the div OR content from clicked div/image into a div that I'll set up below the clear fix -->

<div style="display: block; clear: both;"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myScroll = new iScroll('testBox');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.
- Ken B.

Comment: Posting a relevant part of the HTML (we don't need to see 90+ images), and a more detailed explanation of what you're trying to achieve, would go a long way. Though generally vague questions like this get closed if they're not improved - we expect specific questions about implementation.

Comment: Well it's basically just a list of images. Think of it as choosing an avatar from a list. When I select one of them, I want it to appear inside the target div. Is it that vague? :x

Comment: Most JavaScript (and this is no exception) is written to interact with elements - defined using HTML - on the page. In order to write that JavaScript we need to know the structure of the page otherwise we're just guessing. Asking you to provide us with *what you already have* didn't seem like such a big deal to me, to be honest.

Comment: I just assumed it was simple enough to understand. Edited my post.

Comment: My answer below can fit into your code if you add a class to every selectable div and add an id to the cloned div. (league of legends i see :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (you need Jquery libary loaded)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.selecters").click(

    function () {
        $("#clone").html($(this).html());
    });
});
```

This is an example, it would not work on your HTML unless i guessed lucky with my classes and id's

[Here is a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Burnacid/yQ6Bf/)

Comment: Yes, league of legends. Hehe.. Just trying to make a helpfull iPad app for myself. This will probably work, although I might end up with a problem. Cause in the end I want to be able to select 5 different avatars to go into 5 different divs. But I'll probably figure it out, wont be able to test this right now.

Comment: That wouldn't be that hard, you could check if the div is empty or save it to an invisible div and then click the div you like it to be copied to. then copy from the invisible div to the div you selected. (ps. mark question as answered)

Answer (score 0):

read about :target in css3 
its pretty easy 
with CSS3 no much use of JS
read a simple but great tutorial

[On css3-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css3-tabs/)

[and the demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/)
it really worth reading